# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) in foreach range

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have got one issue from App Store Crashes.

```
0   App                         0x00000001000e0930 _TFC6App22LAnswersBaseController16setupButtonNamesfT_T_ + 620 (LAnswersBaseController.swift:0)
1   App                         0x00000001000f4cb4 _TToFC6App21LAnswersABCController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 64 (LAnswersABCController.swift:26)
```

It is crazy error because I can't reproduce this.

```
class LAnswersBaseController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var examButtons: [LExamButton]!
    var answers: [LAnswerItem] = [LAnswerItem]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupButtonNames()
    }

    func setupButtonNames() {
        for i in 0..<examButtons.count {
            let button = examButtons[i]
            button.titleLabel.text = answers[i].label
        }
    }
}
```

This controller is inflated from Story Board and attached to other controller as child.

ExamButtons are connected in Storyboard ...

1000 users and one crash on iPhone 7 (10.3).

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: How does this work at all? `answers` is an empty array.

Comment: I think about answers, but it isn't this issue. answers are set after create controller in custom segue. Like this: answersController.answers = answers

Comment: So to check if the reason of the crash is `answer`, you might need to declare it as optional and do "optional binding"...

Comment: If answers are empty then error is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION